# Is it possible to populate HTML table from a remote database in Android?

Tags: java, android, html, css

I am trying to get data from a remote database and show it on ANDROID using the HTML table. I am pretty lost. Please help me with this suggest me if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, there is a default table for android that you can use:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="138dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableLayout>
```

This shows 3 rows with 1 column

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have asked for any HTML way.

Comment: @mithun_ghose you can't use html elements in android. Android have its own elements that you can use